# Google Sheets - Create Data Validation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to create several hundred data validation dropdowns that will refer to different ranges.

Dropdowns needs to be created in each cell of sheet1, in column 'O'.
However each dropdown has to refer to a different row in another sheet ('sheet2').

For example:

- data validation dropdown in 'sheet1', cell 'O2' will refer to an entire row 1 in 'sheet2'
- dropdown in 'sheet1', cell 'O3' will refer to a row 2 in 'sheet2', and so on.

Data validation setup:
List from range, show dropdown list in a cell, reject input.

I'd appreciate if you guys could help out with a script that will create predefined number of such dropdowns in a column.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use this sample code:

```
function createDataValidation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var s2_lastRow = s2.getLastRow();

  //create data validation per row 
  for (var row = 1; row <= s2_lastRow; row++){
    
    //create an a1Notation to select a complete row sample: "A1:1", "A2:2", and so on.
    var a1Notation = "A"+row+":"+row;

    //create data validation rule
    var listRange = s2.getRange(a1Notation);
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                  .requireValueInRange(listRange, true)
                  .setAllowInvalid(false)
                  .build();

    //assign rule to the current cell in sheet1 column "O"
    //add 1 row offset since data validation will start at cell "O2"
    a1Notation = "O"+(row+1);
    Logger.log(a1Notation);
    var cell = s1.getRange(a1Notation);
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  }

}
```

### What it does?

1. Get individual sheets using [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
2. Get Sheet2's last row number using [Sheet.getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
3. Loop each individual row in Sheet2
4. Create an `a1Notation` string for the current row using this format (row1: "A1:1")
5. Select a range to be used for the data validation using [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
6. Create a new data validation rule using [SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newdatavalidation). This will return a [DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder) where you can specify what type of data validation to use. For Values in Range, use [DataValidationBuilder.requireValueInRange(range, showDropdown)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange,-showdropdown)

> Regarding rejecting inputs, by default new data validation rules set it to **true**. See [DataValidationBuilder.setAllowInvalid(allowInvalidData)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#setallowinvalidallowinvaliddata)

9. Set newly created data validation rule for a specific cell using [Range.setDataValidation(rule)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationrule)

---

### OUTPUT:

**Sample Sheet2:**

[image]

**Sample Output Sheet1:**

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. One more question though, can we change the validation so that it's set up on the entire row of Sheet2?

Comment: What do you mean? can you explain further? the data validation values are already based on each row entries available in sheet2.

Comment: Sheet2 contains 'indirect' formula, so the values there change depending on the selection in a different field on sheet1. That's why taking last column into consideration won't give the accurate validation range. So to simplify it, it would be best to just include entire row in the validation.

Comment: Have you tried this in your current sheet? What this code should do is to get the complete row value, and filter it out those non-empty cells in that row. The only values that will be added in the data validation rules are those non-empty cells in the current row? If we don't filter that out, you will have that empty cells added in your data validation. Please try it first in your sheet then let me know if what issues you encountered

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. The issue is that the values in sheet2 are changing dynamically. So one row can have 3 columns at the time I run the script. But later on the same row can have 20 columns. Given that multiple users are using the sheet I just want to use the script once, when I need it. Putting the validation range on an entire row in sheet2 will allow to capture all dynamic values.

Comment: Hi please refer to the updated code. This should set the data validation range to the complete row. I removed counting the non-empty cells. Tried it and additional values can be added dynamically